# Trying to understand SQL counting and parsing to php

Tags: sql, mariadb

im new to programming and SQL ( im using maria db ) and trying to understand some specifics on counting.
I have a table with few hundreds  records and some columns ( column1, column2, column3 etc) My column1 contains letters AA or BB or CC etc. column2 contains numbers 1,2,3 etc . and i want to know how many rows are with letters AA in column1  and what is SUM in ( numbers from column2) where column1 contains AA letters  and do this for each letters. As i want to try to parse it out to php as if i understand, i can not have multiple sql queries or can i ?

```
column1 | column2
aa      |   5
aa      |   5
bb      |   8
bb      |   2
bb      |   6
cc      |   3
cc      |   3
```

Thank You.

Have not tried anything yet but was looking towards MAX,SUM, COUNT and DISTINCT but got lost in between

Comment: _"I can not have multiple sql queries or can I"_ Yes, we can. I'd however suggest to edit the question and show the expected result with the given test data

Comment: I have no idea how to start thats why im asking :) have no data to imply ..

Comment: You said _"I have a table"_ and showed two columns and seven rows. Assuming that's your data and you want to run an SQL "Select..." query, then you'd probably do it to get an "expected result"? -- what result do you want to see that would match the narrative description?

Comment: My table contains 70+ columns, so i wont write them down, these 2 columns i wrote is an example as its hard for me to explain due to English is not my language. To be more precise - letter column are states and number column are earnings. but i see an answer already which is close to what i need and a starting point.

Comment: You seem to use columns as if they were rows. Better have a "states" table and one for "earnings". In a relational database, the number of tables normally would not change dynamically, same for the tables' columns. The number of rows is the scalable part in the first place. https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=database%20design%20tutorial

Answer (score 0):

> How many rows are with letters AA in column1 and what is SUM in ( numbers from column2)

A simple aggregate should suffice:

```
select column1, count(*) Num_rows, sum(column2) Column2_Total
from t
where column1 = 'AA' /* <-- optional, remove for aggregate of all rows */
group by column1;
```

Comment: thank you ... i will try this  and will try to dissect it by AA,BB etc..